# Memory Leak in Express.js with EventSource

Tags: node.js, express, memory-leaks, server-sent-events

I think I am running into a memory leak with an **Express** app when connecting x number of **EventSource** clients to it. After connecting the clients and sending them x messages and disconnecting them, my **Express** app only releases a small amount of the allocated Heap/RSS.

To confirm this I saved a **Heapdump** when starting the server and one after connecting 7,000 clients to it and sending x messages to each client. I waited for a while to give the GC a chance to clean up before taking the heap snapshot.

To compare these heap snapshots I loaded them in the Chrome Developer Tools Profile view and chose the "Comparison" mode.

My questions are:

**1)** How to interpret these numbers?
*(For reference see the attached heap snapshot screenshot.)*

**2)** For instance it looks like that the **Socket** objects doesn't almost free any objects at all, is that correct?

**3)** Can you give me more tips to investigate the problem?

[image: Heap Snapshot Express.js app]

Comment: If any one is interested in the code I use to test it, it's here: [Server & Client Code](https://gist.github.com/roundrobin/a6e3d38cb24fcc112418)

Comment: it's not a memory leak you have added a reference to them and not removed it it wont free up the memory while you can still access it. `ALL_CLIENTS` is having stuff added to it now you're closing them there not being removed from `ALL_CLIENTS` so there is still a reference to them once you have finished and connection closed call `delete ALL_CLIENT[key]` where key is the Key of the current client if you have a reference it cant remove the data in there other wise you could potentially have a reference to another apps memory if jumped in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be free from memory leak and as a bonus avoid the garbage collector.
All you got to do is object polling.

You could do something like

```
var clientsPool = new Array(1000);
var clientsConnected = [];
```

When a new client connects, you do

```
var newClient = clientsPool.pop();
//set your props here
clientsConnected.push(newClient);
```

That's an awesome way to avoid the Garbage Collector and prevent memory leak. Sure, there's a little more work to it and you will have to manage that carefully but it's totally worth for performance.

There's an awesome talk about it, here you go
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWmzxyMf2cE

Comment: steam like 'steal'? If you look very closely, our answers are different. He iterates through all the clients while I do object polling. Also, he uses the delete keyword which is veeery bad. And to sum up.. I swear I didn't copy! Wrote it from my mind, I am not a thief =((

Comment: what happens if you don't want a Pool your idea is awesome if you know exactly how many people are to connect or happy to limit your server connections but what if you don't want it limited? say apache did this and went the most connections are 1000 web sites would be buggered being that 1 page could need 10 or so connections that would mean that only 100 users could connect to that apache server, there are better ways than using delete yes but using a limit is not the way to do it...

Comment: oh just one more thing this is not a memory leak it's memory management memory leak means you have to power off the system to get the memory back (it's locked for all applications and the application using it has exited) only low level langs can do it if you were to have a memory leak in a node.js app it's a bug in node.js not you code

Comment: Check the video I linked in my answer. The first array initialization is just to allocate a huge pool of connections so Garbage Collector doenst mess with you runtime! Lets say you allocate an array with 1000 positions, if you run out you could allocate 1000 more. Doing this you will suffer the pain of allocation only once or twice and will completely avoid the pain o garbage collecting. See, an array is a very cheap object you can put you app to console.log the size of your clients so you can see the peek and allocate that.

Answer (score 1):

As to my Comment...

Javascript can't clear up a section of memory should anything be pointing at it about 2 years ago some one found an exploit and it was quickly closed like that and it works like this

```
var someData = ["THIS IS SOME DATA SAY IT WAS THE SIZE OF A SMALL APPLICATION"];
var somePointer = someData[0];
delete someData;
```

they then injected an application into somePointer as it was a reference to a memory location when there was no data now. hey presto you injected memory.

So if there is a reference like above `somePointer = someData[0];` you cant free the memory until you `delete someData` so you have to remove all references to anything you want cleaning in your case `ALL_CLIENTS.push(this);` on line 64 is making your system memory accessible through ALL_CLIENTS, so what you can do is

Line 157

```
_.each(ALL_CLIENTS, function(client, i) {
                    var u; // holds a undefined value (null, empty, nothing)
                    client.close();
                    //delete ALL_CLIENTS[i];
                    ALL_CLIENTS[i] = u;
                    ALL_CLIENTS.unused++;
                });
```

On another note this is not a memory leak a memory leak is say you had this server you close it if the memory did not free up after you exited it then you have a memory leak if it does clean the memory behind it's self it's not a leak it's just poor memory management

Thanks to @Magus for pointing out that delete is not the best thing you could use however i would never recommend that you implement a limiting structure but you could try

Line 27:
`ALL_CLIENTS.unused = 0;`

Line 64:

```
var u;
if(ALL_CLIENTS.unused > 0){
    for(var i = 0; i < ALL_CLIENTS.length; i++){
        if(ALL_CLIENTS[i] == u){
            ALL_CLIENTS[i] = this;
            ALL_CLIENTS.unused--;
            i = ALL_CLIENTS.length;
        }
    }
}else{
    ALL_CLIENTS.push(this);
}
```

Comment: On this note that is only the first thing i found like that check your code for anymore references you're not deleting when you want to free the memory up

Comment: Please, never use the delete keyword!! It does more harm than good. There is no problem keeping an object in memory if you reuse it later. Keep it all in memory and use the same objects for different clientes, by doing this you will avoid the allocation time, deallocation time(delete keyword will ruin your performance) and garbage collection time. Watch the video I posted on my answer for more information, it's worth it

Comment: I'm not saying that's the best way to do it however it does show the fact that the memory is not leaking, however your outline is not the best solution as keeping track of witch connections are present and not present get's quite load heavy, and what version of ECMAScript are you saying it will ruin performance as im sure the delete keyword is only used to tell the cleaner that it can clean it when the cleaner run's it does not forcefully run the cleaner...

Comment: @Magus i have updated to show implementation that allows reuse and dose not invoke delete however i'm sure you're wrong about delete im sure it's supposed to alert the cleaner that it can clean that now and sets the value to `undefined` so lower load on memory cleaner as it does not have to check if it can be removed or not it's been told it can be removed then the cleaner will just lock off any references

Comment: @MartinBarker, I may be wrong but I'm pretty confident. I learned about the keyword in codeschool javascript best practices course. The way they thougt is just that, It will mark the memory for collecting but the idea of it beeing bad is that the Garbage Collector will run anyway and get that if you just set to null, using the delete keyword will just get the GC to run more often and impact your performance. Of course, you wont notice that on desktop but too many deletes and GC events will ruin your performance on mobile.